# Setter methods set fields in each others class

Tags: java, setter

I have two classes, Player and Team. A player has a team field, and a team has a playerList field, containing the players on that team. When a player joins a team, the player's team field should be set to that team, and the team's playerList should add the player object joining. This is what I have so far, but is this not very recursive? How can I solve this problem? Example code is provided below.

```
public class Team {

   private ArrayList<Player> playerList;
   
   public void addPlayer(Player player){
      playerList.add(player);
      player.joinTeam(this);
   }

}

public class Player {
   
   private Team team;
   
   public void joinTeam(Team team) {
      this.team = team;
      team.addPlayer(this)
   }

}
```

Comment: Can the same player join the same team twice? Can a player be in multiple teams? If not, what do you expect to happen if a player that was in team A joins another team? You gotta remove them from the player's list in team A too, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, you should only really have one function for a specific type of action. If you want to add a Player to a Team, something like

```java
public class Team {

   private ArrayList<Player> playerList;
   
   public void addPlayer(Player player) {
      playerList.add(player);
      player.setTeam(this);
   }
}

public class Player {
   
   private Team team;
   
   public void setTeam(Team team) {
      this.team = team;
   }
}
```

would be better suited for your task. You only call one method (`addPlayer`) and both actions you want to have happen, will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to make your code work, you should just remove `team.addPlayer(this)` from  the method `joinTeam()`. But now you are just setting  a value to your attribute, so it should be a `setTeam()`.

```
public class Team {

   private ArrayList<Player> playerList;
   
   public void addPlayer(Player player){
      playerList.add(player);
      player.joinTeam(this);
   }

}

public class Player {
   
   private Team team;
   
   public void setTeam(Team team) {
      this.team = team;
   }

}
```